# Use I string to refer to a variable inside dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

Suppose I have the following data:

```
test_df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100))
```

The following works:

```
test_df %>% 
  summarise(y = mean(a))
```

Now suppose that instead of `a` i want to pass a character string

```
string_outcome <- "a" # I want to use this

test_df %>% 
  summarise(y = mean(string_outcome))
```

That won't work. I tried using `!!string_outcome` but that does not work either. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it is a string, convert it to symbol (`sym` from `rlang`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
test_df %>%
     summarise(y = mean(!! rlang::sym(string_outcome)))
```

Or use `summarise_at` which can take strings in `vars` parameter

```
test_df %>%
    summarise_at(vars(string_outcome), list(y = ~  mean(.)))
```

---

Or if we need a single value without any attributes, even `pull` with `mean` can be used

```
test_df %>% 
       pull(string_outcome) %>%
       mean
```